# Whats the difference between a pipeline operator and $()?

Tags: bash, pipe

```
mint@mint-VirtualBox:/$ ls -l $(which cp)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 153976 Sep  5  2019 /usr/bin/cp
mint@mint-VirtualBox:/$ which cp | ls -l
total 1043228
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          7 Jan 21 15:09 bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root       4096 Jan 21 15:22 boot
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 Jan 21 15:10 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  18 root root       4100 Jan 22 20:33 dev
drwxr-xr-x 149 root root      12288 Jan 21 15:22 etc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root       4096 Jan 21 15:11 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          7 Jan 21 15:09 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          9 Jan 21 15:09 lib32 -> usr/lib32
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          9 Jan 21 15:09 lib64 -> usr/lib64
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         10 Jan 21 15:09 libx32 -> usr/libx32
drwx------   2 root root      16384 Jan 21 15:09 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 Jan  3 18:00 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 Jan  3 18:00 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 Jan  3 18:00 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 162 root root          0 Jan 22 20:33 proc
drwx------   3 root root       4096 Jan 21 22:21 root
drwxr-xr-x  35 root root        960 Jan 22 20:38 run
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          8 Jan 21 15:09 sbin -> usr/sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 Jan  3 18:00 srv
-rw-------   1 root root 1068185600 Jan 21 15:09 swapfile
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root          0 Jan 22 20:33 sys
drwxrwxrwt  15 root root       4096 Jan 22 20:38 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  14 root root       4096 Jan  3 18:00 usr
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root       4096 Jan  3 18:34 var
mint@mint-VirtualBox:/$
```

Why do this two commands produce a different result? Thought the pipeline operator connects the output of one command with the input of a second one and since the output of `which cp` is the path of `cp` it should work or shouldn't it?

Thx for your time in advance, greetings!

Answer (score 1):

```
which cp | ls
```

tries to feed the standard output of `which cp` to the standard input of `ls`. But [`ls` POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html) reads:

> **STDIN**
> Not used

So you can't pipe anything into `ls`. On the other hand, in

```
ls "$(which cp)"
```

the output of `which cp` is given as an *argument* to `ls`, which of course accepts arguments (by the way, [quoting command substitutions as above is good practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766)).

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [Quasímodo's
answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1310238/386622) `ls` doesn't operate
on stdin but you can force it to do so:

```
$ which cp | xargs  ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 153976 Sep  5  2019 /usr/bin/cp
```

See more info on xargs by typing `man xargs`.

And see [Why not use “which”? What to use
then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then/85250)